# How PHPWord return a word response object

Tags: php, symfony, phpword

My php symfony document download code content, I am downloading PDF and docx, I can get PDF response object as return but can not return a docx response object. here my code for docx download,

```
public function getDocxBuilder()
{
    if (is_null($this->docxBuilder)) {
        $this->docxBuilder = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    }

    return $this->docxBuilder;
}

public function setMarginArray($parameterArray, $fileType)
{
    $this->name = isset($parameterArray['name']) ? $parameterArray['name'] : 'document';
    $pageSize = isset($parameterArray['pageSize']) ? $parameterArray['pageSize'] : 'A4';
    $marginLeft = isset($parameterArray['margin_left']) ? $parameterArray['margin_left'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginRight = isset($parameterArray['margin_right']) ? $parameterArray['margin_right'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginTop = isset($parameterArray['margin_top']) ? $parameterArray['margin_top'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginBottom = isset($parameterArray['margin_bottom']) ? $parameterArray['margin_bottom'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);

    return [
        'pageSize' => $pageSize,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'marginLeft' => $marginLeft,
        'marginRight' => $marginRight,
        'marginTop' => $marginTop,
        'marginBottom' => $marginBottom
    ];
}

public function exportDocument($parameterArray, $content)
{
    $pageOption = $this->setMarginArray($parameterArray, $fileType = 'docx');
    $this->getDocx($content, $pageOption);
}

protected function getDocx($content, $sectionStyle)
{
    $section = $this->getDocxBuilder()->addSection($sectionStyle);
    $content = preg_replace("/<table\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/table>/is", "<table style=\"border: 6px #000000 solid;\">$2</table>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("<p><div style=' page-break-after:always !important;'></div></p>", "<pagebreak></pagebreak>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $content);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($this->docxBuilder, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Word download functionality working but, I want to return a word response object for my REST API, for my above code is being returned null. I searched much about this but could not find How return a php/word response object.

Comment: What version of PHPWord is this?

Comment: how check the php/word version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return a Symfony Response with the file. A Streamed response is best suited for that.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="default")
 */
public function index(): Response
{
    return $this->exportDocument([], 'test');
}

public function getDocxBuilder()
{
    if (is_null($this->docxBuilder)) {
        $this->docxBuilder = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    }

    return $this->docxBuilder;
}

public function setMarginArray($parameterArray, $fileType)
{

    $this->name   = isset($parameterArray['name']) ? $parameterArray['name'] : 'document';
    $pageSize     = isset($parameterArray['pageSize']) ? $parameterArray['pageSize'] : 'A4';
    $marginLeft   = isset($parameterArray['margin_left']) ? $parameterArray['margin_left'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginRight  = isset($parameterArray['margin_right']) ? $parameterArray['margin_right'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginTop    = isset($parameterArray['margin_top']) ? $parameterArray['margin_top'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);
    $marginBottom = isset($parameterArray['margin_bottom']) ? $parameterArray['margin_bottom'] : ($fileType == "PDF" ? '10mm' : 600);

    return [
        'pageSize'     => $pageSize,
        'name'         => $this->name,
        'marginLeft'   => $marginLeft,
        'marginRight'  => $marginRight,
        'marginTop'    => $marginTop,
        'marginBottom' => $marginBottom
    ];
}

public function exportDocument($parameterArray, $content)
{
    $pageOption = $this->setMarginArray($parameterArray, $fileType = 'docx');
    return $this->getDocx($content, $pageOption);
}

protected function getDocx($content, $sectionStyle)
{
    $section = $this->getDocxBuilder()->addSection($sectionStyle);
    $content = preg_replace("/<table\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/table>/is",
        "<table style=\"border: 6px #000000 solid;\">$2</table>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("<p><div style=' page-break-after:always !important;'></div></p>",
        "<pagebreak></pagebreak>", $content);
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $content);

    // The latest version of PHPWord is using IOFactory from the PhpOffice\PhpWord namespace
    // instead of the PHPWord_IOFactory, you might want to change it back.
    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($this->docxBuilder, 'Word2007');

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    // Here we are using the $objWriter in a Callback method.
    // This way we can use php://output within a Symfony Repsonse (StreamedResponse)
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($objWriter) {
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    });
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-word');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
    $disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition(
        HeaderUtils::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'test.docx'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I get in my response #content: null; I use Html::addHtml($section, $content, false, false);